# How to use HttpPostedFile as parameter in controller action method to upload single file using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload a file using AngularJs in MVC. But it is throwing an error with 500 internal server while *Post data*.

In my controller-

```
 [HttpPost]
         public int FileUploadFromAngular(HttpPostedFile fileUploadObj)
         {
            return 1;
         }
```

The method *FileUploadFromAngular*, I am calling from Angular JS controller with a file. In which I have defined a variable like-

```
$scope.uploadFile = function () {
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    console.log('file is ');
    console.dir(file);
    var uploadUrl = "Home/FileUploadFromAngular";
    FileUploadService.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
};
```

It is calling controller method without passing parameter but when I pass parameter as HttpPostedFile in action method, It does not call that method. Please help me to know, how to post file as HTTpPostedFile in action method?

Comment: Use you browser tools (Network tab) to inspect the response (it will give you more details about the error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you won't get the file as parameter. Angular send it with `Request.Files`. you have to retrieve the file like below:

```
     [HttpPost]
     public int FileUploadFromAngular()
     {
        HttpPostedFileBase fileUploadObj= Request.Files[0];
        //for collection
        HttpFileCollectionBase fileUploadObj= Request.Files;
        return 1;
     }
```